# How to select multiple values without hitting control using django forms and the SelectMultiple widget?

Tags: django-forms

I need to have a field of my form that allows multiple selections so I went through the Django documentation and found the widget `SelectMultiple`.
It works but only if I press control while selecting the multiple values otherwise it only keeps the last one clicked which is not ideal...
Are there some parameters that I missed or is there another way to do it?
Thanks.

```
country_selected = forms.CharField(label='Select a country',
widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=COUNTRY_CHOICES))
```